# MySQL partitioning table by date and hour

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table with a timestamp field. This table will have millions of rows every day so the idea is to create partitions by date and hour. Every day I will delete partitions older than 10 days and create the partitions for next day. 
   Can you someone tell me how to define partitions for this case? I could not figure it out.
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use 12 partitions -- 10 days, plus one at each end.  `REORGANIZE PARTITION` to split the *empty*, *future*, partition at the end before the new day; drop the oldest.  All the details, including code, are spelled out in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .

Hourly partitions would lead to over 240 partitions; that large a number slows things down.